# Hive query not working as expected

Tags: sql, hive, logic, hiveql, mysql-logic

```
id                      bigint                  from deserializer   
created_at              string                  from deserializer   
source                  string                  from deserializer   
favorited               boolean                 from deserializer   
retweeted_status        struct<text:string,user:struct<screen_name:string,name:string>,retweet_count:int>   from deserializer   
entities                struct<urls:array<struct<expanded_url:string>>,user_mentions:array<struct<screen_name:string,name:string>>,hashtags:array<struct<text:string>>> from deserializer   
text                    string                  from deserializer   
user                    struct<screen_name:string,name:string,friends_count:int,followers_count:int,statuses_count:int,verified:boolean,utc_offset:int,time_zone:string,location:string>    from deserializer   
in_reply_to_screen_name string                  from deserializer
```

.

```
select  id from election order by election.retweeted_status.retweet_count desc  limit 10
```

This query is not working 
the error is "SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 1:53 Invalid column reference 'retweeted_status'"

```
 select  * from election order by election.retweeted_status.retweet_count desc  limit 10
```

But this query is working

Comment: My 2 cents: you cannot `ORDER BY` something that is not present in the `SELECT`.

Comment: BTW, what's the point of that silly tag "mysql-logic" -- even assuming that there is any "logic" in MySQL, here you are running a **Hive** query.

Comment: So maybe the question should be labeled *Developer not working as expected by database*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query executes in below sequence

1 FROM clause

2 WHERE clause

3 GROUP BY clause

4 HAVING clause

5 SELECT clause

6 ORDER BY clause

7 limit

As order executes after we have got result set from select clause, as you have not selected column in select clause orderby clause will not able to find the column reference to perform operation.